# KeyError: 'Dayofweek'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Seems `fastai` library is not working on Python. However, I have tried to add feature using the following lines of code with an objective that should identify whether a given day is

```
Monday/Friday or Tuesday/Wednesday/Thursday.
```

**The code is as follows**

```
    data['mon_fri'] = 0
    for i in range(0,len(data)):
    if (data['Dayofweek'][i] == 0 or data['Dayofweek'][i] == 4):
    data['mon_fri'][i] = 1
    else:
    data['mon_fri'][i] = 0
```

when i run, getting the following error -

> KeyError: '`Dayofweek`'

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Share a snap of your data. According to the error, you are missing the feature in your data

Comment: Date
1999-12-31    17.6875
2000-01-03    17.6875
2000-01-04    17.4375
2000-01-05    17.7500
2000-01-06    17.7500

Comment: date as in index column, values in column 1

Comment: if your column is date, then why are you using `Dayofweek`

Comment: hypothesis is that 1st and 4th days of the week potentially affect the stock price than the other days. So, I am trying to add a feature as predictors to train the model and check the result. I want to create a feature that identifies whether a given day is Monday/Friday or Tuesday/Wednesday/Thursday like that.

Comment: in simple term, want to add another column showing the day of week is equal to 0 or 4, the column value will be 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New answer showing the entire dataframe.

```
In [51]: df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':range(9)})

In [52]: df['d'] = pd.date_range('2016-12-31','2017-01-08',freq='D')

In [53]: df
Out[53]:
   col1          d
0     0 2016-12-31
1     1 2017-01-01
2     2 2017-01-02
3     3 2017-01-03
4     4 2017-01-04
5     5 2017-01-05
6     6 2017-01-06
7     7 2017-01-07
8     8 2017-01-08
```

Now adding column for day of the week

```
In [54]: df['dow'] = df['d'].dt.dayofweek

In [55]: df
Out[55]:
   col1          d  dow
0     0 2016-12-31    5
1     1 2017-01-01    6
2     2 2017-01-02    0
3     3 2017-01-03    1
4     4 2017-01-04    2
5     5 2017-01-05    3
6     6 2017-01-06    4
7     7 2017-01-07    5
8     8 2017-01-08    6
```

Finally doing the calculation, 1 for M/Th 0 for other days

```
In [56]: df['feature'] = df['dow'].apply(lambda x: int((x==1) or (x==4)))

In [57]: df
Out[57]:
   col1          d  dow  feature
0     0 2016-12-31    5        0
1     1 2017-01-01    6        0
2     2 2017-01-02    0        0
3     3 2017-01-03    1        1
4     4 2017-01-04    2        0
5     5 2017-01-05    3        0
6     6 2017-01-06    4        1
7     7 2017-01-07    5        0
8     8 2017-01-08    6        0
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using pandas you can just use the built in dayofweek function

```
In [32]: d = pd.date_range('2016-12-31', '2017-01-08', freq='D').to_series()

In [33]: d
Out[33]:
2016-12-31   2016-12-31
2017-01-01   2017-01-01
2017-01-02   2017-01-02
2017-01-03   2017-01-03
2017-01-04   2017-01-04
2017-01-05   2017-01-05
2017-01-06   2017-01-06
2017-01-07   2017-01-07
2017-01-08   2017-01-08
Freq: D, dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [34]: s = (d.dt.dayofweek==1) |(d.dt.dayofweek==4)

In [35]: s
Out[35]:
2016-12-31    False
2017-01-01    False
2017-01-02    False
2017-01-03     True
2017-01-04    False
2017-01-05    False
2017-01-06     True
2017-01-07    False
2017-01-08    False
Freq: D, dtype: bool
```

Then convert to 1/0 simply by

```
In [39]: t = s.apply(lambda x: int(x==True))
In [40]: t
Out[40]:
2016-12-31    0
2017-01-01    0
2017-01-02    0
2017-01-03    1
2017-01-04    0
2017-01-05    0
2017-01-06    1
2017-01-07    0
2017-01-08    0
Freq: D, dtype: int64
```

Comment: This looks a good starting point, Thanks ! I want to create a function to create values (If the day of week is equal to 0 (Monday) or 4 (Friday), the column value will return 1, else 0)

Comment: You mean do all these steps and add the new column in old data set?

Comment: I want the column header to look like - data(index), values(col1), Feature(col2)

Comment: I think, easiest way to do is iterate through each row and assign the datatype using column ‘Feature’. If you have a solution to this, appreciate your help.

Comment: I did it into a new series just for clarification.  If you want it back into the same dataset that is straightforward. See the update.